# "Failed to load resource" regarding .ogg files on Chrome

Tags: html5-audio

I start playing an .ogg file on Chrome, and it plays for maybe a minute or so, and then it fails to load. I get the failed to load resource error.  Very strange that it would play the .ogg file and then stop.

Probably a streaming issue?...

This does not happen in ff23, or IE10(!).

Here is the url: http://inetwebdesign.com/ClassicalComposers.html

Thanks.

Regards,
umbregachoong

Comment: Evening opening `http://inetwebdesign.com/Couplets_de_folies.ogg` in a new tab fails for me in Chrome v28 after 1:53 -- guessing it's something to do with how you're serving it

Comment: I get the "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING" on chrome and opera, but not Firefox and IE

Answer (score 0):

This is likely related to this known/reported Chromium issue, which is still outstanding as of now (and also affecting a project I'm working on):

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=158245

It can be a difficult bug to reproduce, but appears to be related to the way Chrome 'responsibly' uses bandwidth and does not buffer the entire file immediately, but inches it along as it needs it.

The workaround for us has been to use a Flash fallback for playing audio (we're using SoundManager2), which will bypass the HTML5 Audio player in Chrome. The Flash player will load the entire audio file before starting playback, which is not awesome, but fixes this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the following simple steps:

1. to clean the browser history, and then
2. to close and run once again the browser
3. to open your site once again

You can also try to turn off all your browser extensions temporary.